# I am trying to convert my kivy app to windows exe but I don't have a separate .kv file instead have a in line builder.load_string in the main.py code

Tags: python, kivy, pyinstaller, kivymd

I'm currently working on a kivy app that I want to convert to windows exe just to ensure its working properly. I have installed pyinstaller already along with all the necessary components but when I convert it and modify the spec sheet as instructed from YouTube tutorials I end up coming short because I don't have a separate.kv file as I use the builder.loader_string to style the GUI interface. How would I go about referencing that in line builder in the spec file for my kivy app in order to convert it to exe completely.

Comment: You shouldn't need to reference it in the `.spec` file.

Comment: did you run in console to see full error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Thank you John Anderson. I thought I needed to reference it so it concerned me.

Comment: @furas noted when I ran the app using auto py to exe before using pyinstaller. The error code was no module named kivymd and PIL. I will create another question with the format u have suggested and put the traceback error in the question